Injective modules and divisible modules
My professor has defined a divisible $R$-module as an $R$-module such that for every $0\neq r\in R$ we have $rM=M$. He has also taught us that over a ring with no right or left zero divisors every injective module is divisible. I don't understand where his proof uses the fact that $R$ doesn't have a zero divisor. His proof goes as follows: Let $Q$ be an injective module and $y\in Q$. To prove divisibility we have to show that for any $0\neq a\in R$ the equation $ax=y$ has a solution in $Q$. Now define $I=Ra$ and $f\colon I\to Q$ by $f(ra)=ry$ so $f(a)=y$. According to Baer's criterion there is a $q\in Q$ such that for every $i\in I$ we have $f(i)=iq$. Now we have $f(a)=aq=y$ so $q$ satisfies our equation.

That definition of a divisible module doesn't make any sense. Take $r=0$. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisibleModule.html for example for the good definition.

I believe you need to assume that $r$ is not a zero divisor. Otherwise only the trivial module would satisfy that.

@MartinBrandenburg I edited the question.

@Mark The definition at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/divisible+module doesn't assume that.

@Navid Look carefully, in this link they assume $R$ is an integral domain, in which case $0$ is the only zero divisor. In general, you need to assume $r$ is not a zero divisor. (this is written in the very next line in your link, by the way)

@Mark Thank you.

The assumption that $a$ is not a zero-divisor is used in the proof to define the function $f$. Without that assumption, you could have $ra=sa$ while $ry\neq sy$, and then $f$ wouldn't be well-defined.

@AndreasBlass Seems to be an answer to me.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593877/injective-but-not-divisible-module (but there a wrong def' is used)

Very related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905000

In the Database of Module Examples, this version of divisibility is called "divisible (naive)"  As an example of an injective module that isn't naively divisible, you can just take the ring $R=M=M_2(\mathbb Q)$ as a right module over itself.  It's injective as a right $R$ module, but there are clearly matrices $X$ such that $MX\neq M$.
A better definition of "divisible module $M$" is

For any $x\in M$ and $r\in R$ such that $ann.r(r)\subseteq ann(x)$, there exists $y\in M$ such that $yr=x$.

It turns out this is equivalent to the condition on $M$ that

any $R$ homomorphism from $xR_R\to M_R$ extends to a homomorphism of $R_R\to M_R$

Bridging this gap involves the observations given in the comments above already about well-definedness of the obvious map.
Of course, when $R$ has no zero divisors $ann.r(r)=\{0\}$ for everything nonzero, and you get usual divisibility for domains.
For obvious reasons, a synonym for this type of divisibility is to say "$M$ is principally injective."  Considering Baer's criterion, injective modules are clearly principally injective (i.e., divisible in this other way.)
